# how can I add "starts with" criteria dropdown in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, sqlreportingservice

I want to add **starts with** criteria with dropdown and next to it there will be textbox for entering text that searching starts with like the image link as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can update the data source using your drop down as a parameter and add a where clause to your data source such as

```
AND [ItemNumber] LIKE @parameter + '%'
```